# Get response code using smtp.com with phpmailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

It's possible? Get response code from smtp.com using phpmailer.
I have the list of codes smtp.com, but using the variable $mail->ErrorInfo only get a description of error, I like get the code:

http://www.answersthatwork.com/Download_Area/ATW_Library/Networking/Network__3-SMTP_Server_Status_Codes_and_SMTP_Error_Codes.pdf

Thanks

Comment: `phpmailer` throws a `phpmailerException` in case of an error. Did you take a look into that object?

Comment: Yes, I look into object, but not have the smtp error code, this is a example:phpmailerException Object
(
    [message:protected] => SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last SMTP error by calling `$mail->getSMTPInstance()->getError();`. It returns a structure like this:

```
[
    'error' => '',
    'detail' => '',
    'smtp_code' => '',
    'smtp_code_ex' => ''
]
```

The value you are looking for will be in the `smtp_code` property.

Comment: Which version of phpMailer is the getSMTPInstance() method? I'm using version 5.2.2 and the method does not exist.

Comment: Why are you using an old version? [Upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Ready, I upgrade the phpMailer library, the method exists. I misplace the password to simulate an error, but the array response is empty: Array ( [error] => [detail] => [smtp_code] => [smtp_code_ex] => )

Comment: I am using smtp.com service.